# Java inheritance and overriding a method

Tags: java

I'm just learning about inheritence and am stuck on a simple problem. I want to override the print() statement in the **one** class with a new one in it's subclass **two**. I'm not sure how I would approach it as it is a void statement with no parameters.

```
  public class One {

    private String name;
    private int age;

    public human(String n, int a)
      name = n;
      age = a;
    }
    public void print() {

     System.out.println("Name: " + name);
     System.out.println("Age: " + age);

    }
```

Second class:

```
    public class Two extends One {

    private double gpa;

    public two(String n, int a, double g) {
      super(n,a);
      gpa = g;

    public double getGPA (){
          return gpa;
       }

    public void print() {
    // override code here to include code from class one + displaying GPA..

     }
}
```

So for example, example.print() would print

```
Name: Jack
Age: 34
```

The desired output I want is

```
Name: Jack
Age: 34
GPA: 3.20
```

I am thinking I have to use the super method but cannot find a way to incorporate it correctly. Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: `example.print();` what is reference/object type of `example`  ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The keyword `super` gives you access to (visible) members of the superclass. So, you could call the `print()` method of the superclass, and then just do the specific work of the subclass:

```
public void print() {
    super.print();
    System.out.println ("GPA: " + gpa);
}
```

See this brief section of the Java Tutorials for more on the usage of `super`: [Using the Keyword super](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html). It does address with a simple example the very same problem you were asking about.

Please note that if you wrote

```
public void print() {
    print();
    System.out.println ("GPA: " + gpa);
}
```

Without specifying that you want to call `super.print()`, the `print()` method of `two` would be calling itself indefinitely until you got an `OutOfMemoryError`.

It is also worth noting what Vash mentioned about the [`@Override`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94361) annotation in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15784327/851811).

Answer (score 5):

You've got the right idea.  Try this:

```
public void print() {
    super.print();
    System.out.println("GPA: " + this.gpa);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that comment or the useless one that was added after the code above.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, made a typo which caused compiler errors and thought i wasn't explaining it thoroughly. Thanks...

Answer (score 5):

In Java every method is virtual, this mean that you can override it each accessible method. By accessible method we can take a method that has modifier  public, protected or default.

From Java 1.6, it is recommended to use [annotation `@Override`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94361/when-do-you-use-javas-override-annotation-and-why), to mark the methods that has been override. This help the compiler and developer to prevent potential faults.

So to override method `One#print()` you just have to in child class add method with same [signature](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html).

```
@Override
public void print() {
    super.print(); //Here you call the functionality from super class.
    System.out.println("GPA: %f", getGPA());
}
```

Calling super is not mandatory when overriding.

Nice thing to remember is to add description to method why override was required and do the method call the super class logic.

Answer (score 2):

it is as easy as calling the super() of the method

```
public class one {

private String name;
private int age;

public human(String n, int a);
name = n;
age = a;

public void print() {

System.out.println ("Name: " + name);
System.out.println ("Age: " + age);
Second class:

public class two extends one {

private double gpa;

public two(String n, int a, double g) {
super(n,a);
gpa = g;

public double getGPA (){
      return gpa;
   }

public void print() {
 super.print();
 System.out.println("GPA: " + getGPA());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your One.java

```
public class One {

protected String name;
protected int age;

public One(String n, int a)
{
name = n;
age = a;
}
public void print() {
System.out.println ("Name: " + name);
System.out.println ("Age: " + age);
}
}
```

Two.java

```
public class Two extends One{
private double gpa;

public Two(String n, int a, double g) {
super(n,a);
gpa = g;
}
public double getGPA (){
      return gpa;
   }

public void print() {
    System.out.println ("Name: " + name);
    System.out.println ("Age: " + age);
    System.out.println ("gpa: " + gpa);
}
}
```

Add this in some java file to check the output.

```
public class ExecuteTwo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Two two = new Two("Aiuna",1,100.0);
    two.print();
}
}
```

This will give you what you want.

What you should do after seeing this:
(i) Know what are constructors
(ii) Access modifiers, access levels

Comment: Anuj Balan :- gather information about `super`. `Head first Core java` is best book ever to learn core java. Read it ASAP. Don't miss it.

Comment: You can do that for the OP.

Comment: :-) ignore my comment if you know it.

Answer (score 0):

As you are overriding print() method in class two and you can write in
as `System.out.println("GPA: " + gpa);`